Movie where energy beings possess rockabillies, summoning alien queen through rituals, distorting space-time
I am looking for a movie that I watched around 2010, but it could have been slightly older. I am almost sure it is a post-2000 movie. Aliens made of energy start to possess people, and their first puppets are a group of rockabillies. The movie initially shows what could appear as the demonic possession of a young woman, who instead turns out to be possessed by the queen/goddess of the alien race.
It plays a lot on the border between sci-fi and fantasy, because although the atmosphere is totally sci-fi, there are scenes like one where the main rockabilly summons a forceful manifestation of their queen throughout the body of the possessed girl by hurting himself, pouring his blood on her chest, and using it to draw alien symbols, which in turn start to violently glow with light, making magickal glyphs.
Beside the rockabillies, other preeminent features include the fact that the aliens can enter a state of explicit manifestation of their inhuman nature by entering a trance as they gather near each other and they open their mouths all together contemporaneously, emitting a blinding light from it, and producing a strange noise that is presented to the spectator in such a guise that it is meant to mean that it (in the movie reality) distorts space and time.
Another peculiar passage is where the less hostile, also apparently the less smart among the aliens, put his headphones on the ears of one of the imprisoned humans, like he hoped to share something he liked, perhaps his favourite music, but all that the girl can hear are sinister sounds like metal grinding on metal.
The movie ends with the chief rockabilly allowing the protagonist to escape because he knows (and serenely says, almost without hostility) that they are indeed coming and that the Human Race is doomed. The very final scene shows a vast shadow hoovering, with sounds implying it's the mothership, although the ship itself is not shown (likely to save budget money).

Please do not use generic titles like this. Think of the title of your question as a Google search: would you type this title on Google expecting a useful match? Please change your title to include relevant "search terms", otherwise it adds almost no useful information :)

In roughly which year did you watch this?

Around 2010 but it could have been slightly older

This is The Violent Kind (2010).

One night at a secluded farmhouse deep in the Northern California woods, a small group of hardened young bikers and their girlfriends are tormented when one of the girls becomes savagely possessed and a gang of "Rockabillies" seemingly from the 1950's descends upon them to collect what is growing inside her.

This is a low-budget sci-fi horror film (heavier on the horror than the sci-fi), mostly set at night in and around a remote house near Oakland, California. The protagonist, Cody, is a member of a gang of bikers and drug dealers called The Crew.
Near the start of the film, he attends a birthday party at the aforementioned house 30 miles outside of town. Also in attendance are his ex-girlfriend, Michelle, his best friend, Q (for Quentin), his cousin, Shade (Q's girlfriend), and Michelle's younger sister, Megan.
In the aftermath of the party, when most of the partygoers have left, Michelle inexplicably goes crazy and savagely attacks a couple of guys, getting covered in blood in the process. Cody and Q tie her down on a bed while she screams obscenities at them, like a scene out of The Exorcist.
Later, five strangers show up at the house -- three men named Vernon, Jazz and Murderball, and two women named Trixie and Pussywagon -- and start terrorising Cody and his friends. The men are dressed like greasers and all five  strangers were previously pictured in newspaper clippings about people who went missing in the 1950s.


The Violent Kind (2010)

In the last 15 minutes of the film, Megan asks Murderball -- who, unlike the other strangers, is largely mute and inexpressive -- to let her and her friends go. He responds by placing the headphones he's been wearing the whole time on her ears for a few seconds, but all she hears from them is a weird, pulsating sound.
Shortly after that, Vernon explains that he and the other strangers are extraterrestrials who've been dormant on Earth for the past 60 years and that they've come to the house to get Michelle, who's now a host body for their incubating queen. They lay Michelle's nude, unconscious body on a table, Vernon draws a symbol on her sternum with a bloody finger, then the symbol starts glowing, her body convulses, and the aliens go into a trance-like state with light emanating from their open mouths.
Cody and Megan manage to escape while this is going on. Vernon catches up to them but lets them go, telling them that he's not really doing them a favour and that their kind is a dying breed. They drive into town only to find some people there convulsing and falling down in the streets while others just stare at them blankly. Then they notice what looks like the silhouette of a huge flying saucer looming overhead and producing a loud humming sound as it casts a shadow over their car.




THANK YOU!!!!!!!!. I am ferociously angry at myself because I was all like "The... SOMETHING... kind" in my mind for two days... but I was not even sure so I preferred not to say it in the description, almost superstitiously afraid to suck a potential helper in my same mental loop... I was slowly getting crazy... You cannot understand how grateful I am to you. Thank you, thank you again limitlessly
